# Passing an object to another method and then the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

So I have this index method:

```
 public List<ParkingLot> parkingLot;
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Position postData)
        {
            string json = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }.DownloadString("json_url_removed_for_post");
            parkingLot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ParkingLot>>(json);

            return View(parkingLot);
         }
```

I want to send both the List of ParkingLot objects and the received postData to the About method.

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "hello about";

            return View();
        }
```

How do I go about doing this? And then I want in the about index to be able to display some of the data. How do I pass it from the controller?

Comment: Do not use `TempData` (refresh the browser in the About view and see what happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TempData`:

```
public List<ParkingLot> parkingLot;
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Position postData)
    {
        string json = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }.DownloadString("json_url_removed_for_post");
        parkingLot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ParkingLot>>(json);
        TempData["postData"] = postData;
        TempData["parkingLot"] = parkingLot;
        return View(parkingLot);
     }
```

Then, you can use both them:

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "hello about";
        var postData = (Position)TempData["postData"];
        var parkingLot = (List<ParkingLot>)TempData["parkingLot"];
        return View();
    }
```

Note, that `TempData` requires typecasting, because of storing data as `object`s, and `null` checking.

You can return `postData` to `About` page, like this:

```
return View(postData);
```

Then, in `About` page, at the top, you must write `@model Position`, and then you can use it, wit the help of `Model` class.

Comment: Looks like it works. Now how would I display postData.latitude in the About view?

Comment: @crystyxn Edited the answer.